# Define a case-insensitive dictionary as controller method parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, parameters

Is it possible to define a `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` for a dictionary that's used as input for a method inside a controller?

Right now my best 'solution' is creating a new dictionary and copying the data over inside a filter.

```cs
public IActionResult DoStuff([FromBody] IDictionary<string, object> data)
{
    //do stuff with Case-Insentive dictionary here
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Comment: did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Miky I think OP is aware of this, they're just asking how to use an `IEqualityComparer` without needing to call a `Dictionary` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case-insentive dictionary, you could try to implement your own dictionary like

```
public class CaseInSensitiveDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<string, TValue> 
{
    public CaseInSensitiveDictionary():base(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {

    }
}
```

And then

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DoStuff([FromBody] CaseInSensitiveDictionary<object> data)
    {
        var t1 = data["t1"];
        var T1 = data["T1"];
        //do stuff with Case-Insentive dictionary here
        return StatusCode(200);
    }
```